# Screenshot of Full Screen in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, web, uml, class-diagram

this is  my Class Diagram and i want to take Screenshot of full screen from top to bottom 
is there any option in Visual studio 2012 to take full screen Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Better use Windows **Snipping Tool**

Comment: Sorry its not working 
i m talking about that scroll u can see in the image 
(screenshot from top to bottom according to the scroll)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to save your complete class diagram as an image, just click somewhere inside the editing pane and press `Ctrl+A` to select all classes in the diagram. Now you can copy the diagram to clipboard with `Ctrl+C` and paste it into your favorite image editing program with `Ctrl+V` to get your complete class diagram as an image. You could even select only some of the classes to get an image of a part of the diagram.

More info in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554948.aspx).